# awk + change column value and keep double quotes

Tags: awk

I have this data:

```
$ head test
"Rec Open Date","MSISDN","IMEI"
"2015-01-04",100,200
"2015-01-04",100,200
"2015-01-04",100,200
"2015-01-04",100,200
"2015-01-04",100,200
"2015-01-04",100,200
"2015-01-04",100,200
"2015-01-04",100,200
"2015-01-04",100,200
```

I can use this command to change the value of the first column:

```
$ awk -F, 'NR>1{$1="2015-01-05"}1' OFS=, test > tmpfile && mv tmpfile test
```

with this command I loose the double quotes, I would like to keep the double quotes. Can this command be modified to achive this?

```
$ head test
"Rec Open Date","MSISDN","IMEI"
2015-01-05,100,200
2015-01-05,100,200
2015-01-05,100,200
2015-01-05,100,200
2015-01-05,100,200
2015-01-05,100,200
2015-01-05,100,200
2015-01-05,100,200
2015-01-05,100,200
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from The GNU Awk User’s Guide;

> \" A literal double quote (necessary for string constants only). This
>   sequence is used when you want to write a string constant that
>   contains a double quote. Because the string is delimited by double
>   quotes, you need to escape the quote that is part of the string, in
>   order to tell awk to keep processing the rest of the string.

```
$ awk -F, 'NR>1{$1="\"2015-01-05\""}1' OFS=, test > tmpfile && mv tmpfile test

$ head test
"Rec Open Date","MSISDN","IMEI"
"2015-01-05",100,200
"2015-01-05",100,200
"2015-01-05",100,200
"2015-01-05",100,200
"2015-01-05",100,200
"2015-01-05",100,200
"2015-01-05",100,200
"2015-01-05",100,200
"2015-01-05",100,200
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not that you are "losing" them, but the fact that `$1` is initially `"something"` and you replace it with `another thing`. As this `another thing` is a string, you use double quotes to note it. So to have the double quotes back, you need to indicate so when doing the replacement.

This can be cleaner:

```
awk -v new='"2015-01-05"' 'BEGIN {FS=OFS=","} NR>1{$1=new}1' file
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                              ^
         |---------------------------------------------|
    we provide the var ............... and we replace with it
      surrounded by "
```

Comment: tks for that and all the details